# Workaround for generating variables dynamically in java

Tags: java

I have a problem that I **CANNOT** solve with lists or arrays, which would be very easy. Here is the prompt:

*A large company pays its salespeople on a commission basis. The salespeople 
receive $200 per week plus 9% commission of their gross sales for that week. For 
example, a salesperson who sells $5000 worth of merchandise in a week receives 
$200 plus 9% of $5000, or a total of $650. You are prompt user for the salesperson's 
firstName, lastName, and N number of items sold.
Write a program called Commission that inputs one salesperson's firstName, 
lastName, and the number of items and quantity of each iterm sold for last week and 
calculates and display that salesperson's firstName, lastName, and earnings. There 
is no limit to the number of items sold by a salesperson.
Note: we are not working with lists or arrays; store item type and value in variables for 
later computations.*

There are sophisticated methods for dealing with class reloading, but I'm not familiar with them. I don't know how I can account for a variable number of items. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Why do you need to generate variables dynamically for this? And why exactly is a list not appropriate for the items sold?

Comment: (Also, the fact this question is substantially a copy-pasted homework assignment doesn't help.)

Comment: no lists or arrays huh? How about a Map? Item is the key, quantity is the value, increment the count on duplicate items.

Comment: Perhaps dynamically isn't the appropriate term, but I need to be able to have a variable number of items. The prompt says that I can't use lists or arrays, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: the list is enough for this case, you don't need to dynamically generate variable, not only that if you do it will be a bad method.

Comment: It's heavily different to say *I **CANNOT** solve with lists or arrays* than *I'm forbidden to use lists or arrays to solve this problem*.

Comment: Generally, arbitrary homework restrictions need to be spelled out on SO - most of the people answering aren't really used to them.

Comment: I'm not asking for code, I'm asking to be pointed in the right direction. I want to use an array or list, but we haven't covered those, so they're off-limits. There must be a simple solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The implication that arrays and lists are forbidden is contained in the phrase, "which would be very easy." But millimoose makes a good point; I should've spelled this out.

Comment: Wehre does the prompt say you cannot use a list? You just need a number of items (it doesn't even say that each item needs to be specified any further such as name or whatever) So it's simply item no 1 - quantity, item no 2 - quantity. I would suggest to use a map as digitaljoel said...

Comment: But do you need to keep the information somewhere? I don't see that requirement, just perform the calculation and output it. No need to store it anywhere.

Comment: I just appended the prompt.

Comment: @Lee not all the people would understand what you mean, next time you should be more concise in your sentences to explain the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use a loop: read in the items and quantities, add to the earnings. There is no need for a list or array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remember the individual sales to calculate the desired results.

Just sum up the sales per person when they are entered. All the information you need is the sum, for the calculation you do not care how the sum is composed.

You can do this with a number of nested loops, one the outermost loops persons, the inner loops items. At the start of the item loop you initialize the sum to zero, with eacj loop iteration you add the items sale value. After the inner loop completes, calculate the earnings and display them. Move on to the next person. Simple?